# Arduino 2006 how to connect to my laptop?

Tags: arduino, connection

I have borrowed an Arduino BT-V06 (analogue) from my college IT storage department.

At home I am trying to do some research on this for subsequent work I am going to perform with this Arduino later on. As this model is a 2006 version; my question is, how do I connect it to my laptop? Some sort of adapter? or perhaps shield it with a newer model that has a usb-port?

Because I would like to have it connected to my laptop in order to try out some codes on it.

Thank you very much for your time!

-M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least two options. First, it's set up to be programmed over Bluetooth. So if you have Bluetooth on your laptop, you can connect the two wirelessly. Pins 0 and 1, per the documentation, are TTL serial transmit and receive pins (which are also used for Bluetooth communications), so if you AREN'T connecting via Bluetooth, you could connect a serial to USB adapter so you can connect to your laptop via USB. [This reference](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoBT) has this to also say:

"The on-board serial communication between the bluetooth module and the Arduino sketch (running on the ATmega328) needs to be at 115200 baud (i.e. call Serial.begin(115200) in your setup() function). Communication between the bluetooth module and the computer can be at any baud rate.

Communication between the BT module and the computer can be temperamental. You might want to open the serial monitor a couple of seconds after resetting the board. The text of the Arduino getting started guide is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 License. Code samples in the guide are released into the public domain."